# The content should always fit into the parent div - use font-size percentage -

Tags: html, css

My pen:

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/zvGgt

When you resize the window vertically to shrink the vertical stacked divs the font-size for the content inside the divs is too small for the single div thus the whole div stack overflows vertically.

I would like to use font-size percentage on the stack so when the browser window is resized the font-size decreases  so I except that the stack does not overflow because the divs have still space to shrink.

What is the best approach in my situation when I only want that my stack uses font-size percentage but not the rest of the html page.

What do you declare where, please provide a solution where you modify my sample as basis so I can understand it, thank you.

Have a look at this image: My problem is that the text "7" can not be read anymore so I have to shrink/decrease the text...

[image]

**CSS**

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    font-family: arial;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

* { /* Every element which has a border or padding value puts this value inside the div */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

._Z {
    width: 12.50%;
}

.Stack {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

    .Stack li {
        list-style: none;
        display: table-row;
    }

        .Stack li div {
            display: table-cell;
        }

.horizontal-right {
    text-align: right;
}

.horizontal-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.vertical-center {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#responseView {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="responseView" data-bind="swipeLeftRightContentViews: $root.showMapView">
        <div style="height: 100%;"> 
           <ul class="Stack _Z" data-bind="foreach: replyTimeStack.segments">

             <li style="height:14.2%;background: green; color: black;">
                    <div style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">11</div>
                </li>
             <li style="height:14.2%;background: green; color: black;">
                    <div style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">22</div>
                </li>
             <li style="height:14.2%;background: green; color: black;">
                    <div style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;" class="horizontal-center vertical-center">33</div>
                </li>
             <li style="height:14.2%;background: green; color: black;">
                    <div style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">44</div>
                </li>
                <li style="height:14.2%;background: yellow; color: black;">
                    <div style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">55</div>
                </li>
              <li style="height:14.2%;background: orange; color: black;">
                    <div style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">33</div>
                </li>
              <li style="height:14.2%;background: green; color: black;">
                    <div style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">66</div>
                </li>

            </ul> 

        </div>       
   </div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Text doesn't overflow. Tested in chrome and IE 10.

Comment: Does not overflow for me either. Why don't you just set a min height property to your divs?

Comment: @ALL I have updated my init post with an image to show the problem. Sorry maybe I confused you with the work "overflow"...

Comment: I think you're confused about how `font-size: x%` works, [it's based on the font size of the parent element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).

Comment: @steveax YES... but thats what I want: when the parent div with number 7 shrinks then the font-size should shrink too so I can still read "7" on small mobiles AND desktop browser with a small height...